# Using list() on cycle object hangs system

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools, cycle

I'm trying to cycle through the elements of an array `aa`, where the `for` block is not applied over it but over another array `bb`.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import cycle

aa = np.array([[399., 5., 9.], [9., 35., 2.], [.6, 15., 8842.]])
c_aa = cycle(aa)

bb = np.array([33, 1., 12, 644, 234, 77, 194, 70])
for _ in bb:
    print(c_aa)
```

This does not work, it simply outputs:

```
<itertools.cycle object at 0x7f8d207b1640>
<itertools.cycle object at 0x7f8d207b1640>
<itertools.cycle object at 0x7f8d207b1640>
<itertools.cycle object at 0x7f8d207b1640>
<itertools.cycle object at 0x7f8d207b1640>
<itertools.cycle object at 0x7f8d207b1640>
<itertools.cycle object at 0x7f8d207b1640>
<itertools.cycle object at 0x7f8d207b1640>
```

But if I change that last line for `print(list(c_aa))` my entire system almost hangs.

What is going on here and how can I iterate over `aa` without using it in the `for` call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the cycle goes infinitely, calling `list()` on it is a bad idea, as you've discovered. You can call `next()` on the iterator to get the next value, however:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import cycle

aa = np.array([[399., 5., 9.], [9., 35., 2.], [.6, 15., 8842.]])
c_aa = cycle(aa)

bb = np.array([33, 1., 12, 644, 234, 77, 194, 70])
for _ in bb:
    print(next(c_aa))
```

Comment: I think this is the cleaner option so I'm selecting this one, but Alex's answer is also a good approach. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You need to actually iterate over the cycle, e.g:

```
for b, a_row in zip(bb, cycle(aa)):
  print(b, a_row)
```

Output:

```
33.0 [399.   5.   9.]
1.0 [ 9. 35.  2.]
12.0 [6.000e-01 1.500e+01 8.842e+03]
644.0 [399.   5.   9.]
234.0 [ 9. 35.  2.]
77.0 [6.000e-01 1.500e+01 8.842e+03]
194.0 [399.   5.   9.]
70.0 [ 9. 35.  2.]
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/@alexmojaki/FamiliarPrettyQuark)